# How to read a .man file not on manpath?

Tags: unix, manpage

How do I read a .man file that's not on my manpath? I know I had a command for this, but now I don't remember, and I can't find the right switch in the man pages for man.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can try to read your file by doing

```
man path_to_file
```

as man will treat the given argument as a file if it finds a slash `/` in it.
For instance

```
man ./my_test
```

will open the `my_test` file, while

```
man my_test
```

will look in the standard manual for the given command.

Comment: After an update (man is now v 1.6f), this doesn't work anymore. I guess it's back to nroff. Annoying, I liked this solution so much better :(

Comment: You can try to read your file by doing `man path_to_file`, as `man` will treat the given argument as a file if it finds a slash `/` in it. For instance `man ./my_test` will open the *my_test* file, while `man my_test` will look in the standard manual for the given command.

Comment: @Nagel I forgot to tag you in the last comment, hope it helps

Comment: Awesome, @IceCoder! I can't believe I didn't try that before :P Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 19):

If your man page is in a non-standard directory location, you can use:

```
man -M <path to man directory> mymanpage
```

You can also use the MANPATH environment variable:

```
MANPATH=<path to man directory> man mymanpage
```

If you are looking to format a standalone man page, use nroff:

```
nroff -man mymanpage.1 | less # or your favorite pager
```

Comment: Can't get man -M to work. 

`man -M qnstrn.man` 

gives me `What manual page do you want?`. `man -M qnstrn.man qnstrn` gives me `No manual entry for qnstrn`. `nroff` works, though.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer to distinguish between a non-standard directory and the case of a standalone page.

Comment: To complete the last: `nroff -man mymanpage.1 | pager` (on Debian) or `nroff -man mymanpage.1 | less` (on all Unicies).

Comment: I managed to view a roff man page I had in my clipboard in this way:
`xclip -selection clipboard -o | nroff -man | bat -l man`

Answer (score 4):

The option `-l, --local-file`, as documented in `man man`

```
man -l ./doc/mypage.1
```

Comment: Most elegant solution here, especially since you no longer need the `./` in front of relative paths if you use this option